# What is the standard way of writing O(max(n, m))?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What is the standard way of writing "the big-O of the greatest of m and n"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be written as

```
O(m+n)
```

It might not look the same at first, but it is, since

```
max(m, n) <= m+n <= 2max(m, n)
```

If you want, you can also just write `O(max(m, n))`

Comment: Can you elaborate or give a reference on why it is O(m+n)?

Comment: @svenoaks: Answer expanded.

Comment: @svenoaks `m = n, O(m+n) = O(2n) = O(n); m > n, O(m+n) = O(max(m,n)) O(m)`